# How do i pass a static class as reference and use their methods/members on another class?

Tags: java, class, reference

In Java, i am trying to pass a static class as a parameter and trying to access its methods/members from another class/method.

**Example:**

```
public static Class class1
{
   Some variables..
} 

public static Class class2
{
   Some variables..
}

public class RunnerClass
{
   public <T> void Run(<T> Class cl)
   {
      //if cl is class1, then
        cl.variables ---> This should be class1.variables
      //if cl is class2, then
        cl.variables ---> This should be class2.variables
   }
}
```

Is that possible on java?

Comment: This isn't doable in a clean manner, unfortunately. The best you can do is create an interface and use instances of that interface.

Comment: Or using abstract class that will be class1 and class2 extending

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, But u can't send class within a class. U can send the class reference for it. If you want to use the static methods present in the class just type "classname.method_inside_the_class" (for static methods).If the class is in another package, just import the class by import keyword.